# Flutter: Change Checked Colour of Checkboxes

Tags: flutter, checkbox, bottom-sheet

I am trying to create a bottom sheet with checkboxes[image]. I'm finding it difficult to get the checkboxes to be checked and show a different colour once tapped. At the moment the checkbox just stays empty.

How would I solve this?

```
bool isChecked = false;

...

Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 10, 10, 10),
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(child: Text('Classes Booked')),
                        Checkbox(
                          checkColor: isChecked
                              ? Colors.grey
                              : Theme.of(context).colorScheme.aqua,
                          value: isChecked,
                          onChanged: (bool value) {
                            setState(() {
                              value = true;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

Comment: Value it's actually the new value returned from the checkbox, so in the setState should be only isChecked = value;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you ought do something like :

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
     setState(() {
          isChecked = true;
     });
```

Or something more efficient like :

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
     setState(() {
          isChecked = !isChecked;
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pre-made widget called `CheckboxListTile` which takes care of the layout.

```
class AppHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppHomePageState createState() => _AppHomePageState();
}

class _AppHomePageState extends State<AppHomePage> {
  bool isChecked = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: CheckboxListTile(
        checkColor: Colors.red,  // for the actual check mark
        activeColor: Colors.green,  // for the surrounding box
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: (v) => setState(() => isChecked = v),
        title: Text('foo'),
        subtitle: Text('bar'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

by changing the `checkColor` and `activeColor` you can fix it.